# How to use recursion to produce the sum of powers?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function using only recursion (and no built-in functions) that consumes two numbers, x and y and produces the sum

`1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^(y-1) + x^y`

Note that I am looking for a way to do this **without** using for/while loops because I have not learned them yet. So far, I have the following function:

```
def power_addition (x, y):
    i = 0
    if i < y:
        i = i+1
        return x**i + power_addition (x, y)
    else:
        return x**i
```

As far as I can tell, the code breaks for one particular reason.

Comment: Undefined variable? what is ``n``?

Comment: my bad, i meant y

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def sum_of_powers(x,y):
    if y<=0: return 1
    return x**y + sum_of_powers(x,y-1)
```

Comment: @LenovoUser: why does it have to do it in ascending order?